# Swift - How to tell if Torch is on through control center

Tags: iphone, swift, avfoundation

In my app, I want to check if the torch/flashlight of the iPhone is on or off.  I know how to set up an AVCaptureSession and all that, but that doesn't give me the information I really want to know.  I want to know whether, at the time of the code being called, the phone's torch is on or off from control center.

Comment: What about `AVCaptureDevice isTorchActive` or `AVCaptureDevice torchLevel`?

Comment: @rmaddy torchLevel always returned 0.0 for me, I will check isTorchActive